# Can't change color of item in QListView

Tags: qt, c++11, qt5

I have the following code;

```
  QStringListModel *model = new QStringListModel();
  QStringList list;
  ui.listViewResults->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
  ui.listViewResults->setViewMode(QListView::ListMode);

  list << "A";
  list << "B";
  list << "C";
  model->setStringList(list);

  QModelIndex vIndex = model->index(0, 0);
  QMap<int, QVariant> vMap = model->itemData(vIndex);
  vMap.insert(Qt::BackgroundRole, QVariant(QBrush(Qt::red)));
  model->setItemData(vIndex, vMap);

  ui.listViewResults->setModel(model);
```

Yet, the color does not seem to change, any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: A `QStringListModel` doesn't store anything but strings. Maybe you want a `QStandardItemModel`?

Comment: Thank you @peppe this solved the problem if you'd like to post as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [QStandartItemModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html) and [QStandartItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditem.html) if you need different background for each item. Or you can even make your own model/item subclassing [QAbstractItemModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html)

Example of using [QStandartItemModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html) and [QStandartItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditem.html)

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QStringListModel>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QListView>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel();
    QList<QStandardItem *> list;
    ui->listView->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
    ui->listView->setViewMode(QListView::ListMode);

    list << new QStandardItem("A");
    list << new QStandardItem("B");
    list << new QStandardItem("C");

    model->appendColumn(list);

    QModelIndex vIndex = model->index(0, 0);
    QMap<int, QVariant> vMap = model->itemData(vIndex);
    vMap.insert(Qt::BackgroundRole, QVariant(QBrush(Qt::red)));
    model->setItemData(vIndex, vMap);

    ui->listView->setModel(model);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

[image]